# How to grep any digit from sentence

Tags: bash, text-processing, grep

Could You help me with greping?
I have a:

```
variable="RMN quota:        0 bytes"
```

and

```
variable="RMN quota:        1.56 bytes"
```

The target id to get output: 0 or 1.56.

What will be grep for it?

Comment: it must be read from a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
grep -Eo '[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?' inputfile
```

If you're checking the value of a shell variable rather than the contents of a file, you can do this:

```
echo "$variable" | grep -Eo '[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?'
```

Comment: it must be read from a variable.

Comment: It Rules :) Than You so much :)))

Answer (score 4):

POSIXly:

```
n=${variable% bytes} # strip the trailing " bytes"
n=${n##*[[:blank:]]} # strip the leading part up to the rightmost blank
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have bash:

```
tr -d -c 0-9. <<<$variable
```

(would also work in Zsh).